# How to check if a git commit author is valid

Tags: git, bash, github

In a repository where I cant set both `user.name` and `user.email` configurations I need to script a commit with:

```
commit -a --message "message" --author="author"
```

Message and author are parametrized.

When I commit with a wrong author (not present on `rev-list` and bad formatted for git) I get:

> fatal: --author 'bad-formatted-author' is not 'Name ' and matches no existing author

Is there any way to check against git if the author is valid before the commit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `git commit -a --message "message" --author="author" --dry-run`.

The added `--dry-run` flag will make `git commit` not actually commit anything but still exit non-zero if the `--author` option string given is invalid.

Note, however, that there may be other reasons the exit status is non-zero, such as the commit being empty (i.e. not having any changes).

Answer (score 2):

This really is right in [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html):

> `--author=author`
>
> Override the commit author. Specify an explicit author using the standard `A U Thor <author@example.com>` format. Otherwise *`author`* is assumed to be a pattern and is used to search for an existing commit by that author (i.e. `rev-list --all -i --author=author`); the commit author is then copied from the first such commit found.

You even copied these in your question:

> not present on rev-list and bad formatted for git

which means this is your answer: check the format to see if it matches the `Name <email>` style, and if not, run `git rev-list` with the parameters shown to see if there is at least one matching commit.

In general, though, it's probably simpler to just attempt the commit and catch the failure.